# Camera tracking footage rendering as black

Tags: camera, tracking

I am trying to learn camera tracking to include 3D assets to filmed footage. When I activate rendered view mode everything is black other than the 3d objects. I also can't seem to make the ground become a shadow catcher.

Comment: Do you use Cycles (Eevee has no shadow catcher)? Did you "Set Up Tracking Scene"? Is your Film *transparent* (Render Properties -> Film)?

Comment: Cycles. It turns out that everything was working. I didnt understand how render layers work. The shadows were on the background layer. I didnt know that when you render, it renders the layers 1 by 1 so I was confused. Thank you though.